# How to pass element to anonymus function in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a countdown element and I want to pass each element to setinterval function to update it each second

```
                var countDownDate = new Date($(this).data('date')).getTime();

                setInterval(function() {
                    var now = new Date().getTime();

                    var distance = countDownDate - now;

                    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
                    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

                    $(this).find('.days').text(days);
                    $(this).find('.hours').text(hours);
                    $(this).find('.minutes').text(minutes);
                    $(this).find('.seconds').text(seconds);
                }, 1000);
            });
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What's wrong with the current code?

Comment: doesn't change the elements as $(this) isn't exposed to the function

Comment: Try : `setInterval(() => {`

Comment: There's a big difference between "pass an element to a function" and "using`this` inside a function`  your question title says one, your *comment* says the other.  Please be clear in your question and title.

Comment: Does this answer your question:  [Are arrow functions interchangeable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-interchangeable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your questions don't describe what you really wanted, but there are a few ways to access these elements inside the function.

1. Using an arrow function

```
 setInterval(() => {
   /*
   your code goes here without changes
   */
 }, 1000)
```

2. Passing parameters

```
 setInterval(function(days, hours, minutes, seconds) {
   /*
   your code goes here without changes
   */
   days.text(days);
   hours.text(hours);
   minutes.text(minutes);
   seconds.text(seconds);
 }, 1000, $(this).find('.days'), $(this).find('.hours'), $(this).find('.minutes'), $(this).find('.seconds'))
```

3. Binding

```
setInterval((function() {
  /*
  your code goes here without changes
  */
}).bind(this), 1000)
```

You could just also pass `this` as an argument.
I would use the arrow function since it's a more modern approach.